# Internal Server Error when connecting Heroku to GitHub

Tags: heroku, github-integration

I have the free tier on Heroku so they told me to ask for support on StackOverflow instead of Heroku.

I had a deployment method for my Heroku app set to a GitHub repository and it was working fine. At some point in the past, I believe I changed the name of the repository, but I'm not sure if that part matters.

Today, I logged into Heroku to try and change some environment variables and noticed that it wasn't connected anymore. When attempting to connect to GitHub again by going to `my app > deploy > deployment method > GitHub > Connect to GitHub`, I authorize Heroku to have access to my GitHub repositories, but then I get a red error in the corner saying `Item could not be retrieved: Internal Server Error`. This happens for all of my projects now in Heroku.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? Thanks!

[image]